# Html can not see css files

Tags: html, css, path

i use html template but index can not see css file.. am i do wrong anything

[image: css path]
[image: index.html href tag]
[image: and my localhost...]

How can i fix that ? thank you..

Comment: Try removing the leading `/`

Comment: check the path to your CSS files !!!

Answer (score 0):

-Fixed-
I used middleware but just like this

```
app.use(Express.static('public'))
```

when i was try to another middleware and fixed that's error

```
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

I guess, css path need to __Dirname bcause can not find path.

anyway, FIXED